# SQL server query select multiple ID in one field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to ask how to select data from two table if one tabel have multiple ID

Example:

**Table Request:**

```
RequestNo | supplierID
1231     |   '1','2','3'
```

**Table Supplier**

```
ID   | supplier name
1    |   asin
2    |   acam
3    |   ande
```

I want the select result like this:

**Select Result**

```
RequestNo  | SupplierName
1231 |  asin,acam,ande
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Hi Adryan. Really, I would consider reorganice the table data and make it relational, the field 1,2,3 is a pain in the ass and it should be 3 rows with values 1, 2 and 3.
Then SQL can treat it correctly, otherwise it only can provide problems.

Comment: Fix your data modal

Comment: This is a really broken data model. What happens when suppliers get commas in the name, like `Apple Computer, Inc.`?

Answer (score 2):

If you have sql-server-2017 and above you can use `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG`

```
DECLARE @TableRequest TABLE (RequestNo INT, supplierID VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @TableRequest VALUES
(1231 , '''1'',''2'',''3''')

DECLARE @TableSupplier TABLE (ID  INT, [supplier name] VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @TableSupplier VALUES 
(1 , 'asin'),
(2 , 'acam'),
(3 , 'ande')

SELECT RequestNo, STRING_AGG([supplier name],',') SupplierName 
FROM 
    @TableRequest R
    OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(R.supplierID,',') AS X
    LEFT JOIN  @TableSupplier S ON REPLACE(X.value,'''','') = S.ID
GROUP BY RequestNo
```

Result:

```
RequestNo   SupplierName
----------- ------------------
1231        asin,acam,ande
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `STRING_AGG()` like

```
select r.requestno, string_agg(s.name, ',')
from request r join supplier s
on concat(',', r.supplierid, ',') like concat('%,', s.id, ',%')
group by r.requestno
```

But, don't forgot to fix your data model

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c4ae6055e52c4b5904834d9e5bf16920)